# Does a relative import with a "." always makes sense in python?

Tags: python, import, python-2.7

When a module `mod1.py` and `mod2.py` exists in the same directory, I can import `mod2` in `mod1` directly as

```
import mod2
```

or relative with

```
from . import mod2
```

Is there any preferable way to do this?

I am asking because if `mod1` is imported in `mod2` as well, the relative import will not work.

Comment: Probably the first version is preferable. You should avoid circular references anyway.

Comment: @freakish hit the nail on the head.  If you are trying to find ways to make circular imports work, you've already missed the problem you need to solve.  The real problem is one of design; you need to figure out how to break down the functionality of your program so you don't need to have a circular import.

Comment: I like much more the second syntax, because it makes explicit that the other module is part of your package(and this also helps avoiding conflicts with other packages). The PEP8 says to avoid them but [Guido does not agree with it](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2010-October/104476.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implicit relative imports [are gone in Python 3](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#removed-syntax). So clearly, they are deprecated, primarily because they collide with absolute imports (i.e. if there was a global module mod2, how would you import that?).

You are right that circular explicit relative imports don't work; [this is a bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue992389). As a consequence, the preferable way is to avoid circular imports.